# FeatureCollection (Error) Cannot flatten an object that is not a collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

What is this error? It clearly says we have a `FeatureCollection` then it says `Cannot flatten an object that is not a collection.`

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
Cannot flatten an object that is not a collection.
```

## Reproducible code:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///                           functions definitions start
///
/// Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band.
function maskS2clouds(image) {
    var qa = image.select('QA60');

    // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
    var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
    var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

    // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
                        qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

    // Return the masked and scaled data, without the QA bands.
    return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
                          .select("B.*")
                          .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
/// add Day of Year to an image
///

var addDate_to_image = function(image){
  var doy = image.date().getRelative('day', 'year');
  var doyBand = ee.Image.constant(doy).uint16().rename('doy');
  doyBand = doyBand.updateMask(image.select('B8').mask());

  return image.addBands(doyBand);
};

////////////////////////
///
/// add Day of Year to an imageCollection
///

var addDate_to_collection = function(collec){
  var C = collec.map(addDate_to_image);
  return C;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// add NDVI to an image

var addNDVI_to_image = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////
///
///
/// add NDVI to an imageCollection

var add_NDVI_collection = function(image_IC){
  var NDVI_IC = image_IC.map(addNDVI_to_image);
  return NDVI_IC;
};

var extract_sentinel_IC = function(a_feature){
    // var start_date = 
    // var end_date = 
    // var cloud_percentage = 
    // var geom = ee.Feature(feature_col).geometry();
    var geom = a_feature.geometry();
    var imageC = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                .filterDate('2012-01-01', '2019-12-31')
                .filterBounds(geom)
                //.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', "less_than", 10)
                .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 10));

    imageC = imageC.map(maskS2clouds);
    imageC = imageC.select(['B8', 'B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

    imageC = addDate_to_collection(imageC);
    imageC = add_NDVI_collection(imageC);
    //imageC = imageC.map(add_NDVI_collection)
  return imageC;
};

///
///                         functions definitions end
///
///////////////////////////////////////////////

var city = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-122.42, 37.78, -122.4, 37.8), 
                      {label: 'City'});

var city_IC = extract_sentinel_IC(city);
print (city_IC)
var city_IC_flatten = city_IC.flatten()
print (city_IC_flatten)
```

Comment: Can you please provide your script or an example that reproduces the error so that we can investigate why it is triggered.

Comment: will do in a minute (no one in the world has not seen this before?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error message

```
FeatureCollection (Error)
Cannot flatten an object that is not a collection.
```

the first word being `FeatureCollection` does not mean that the object was a FeatureCollection. Rather, it means that as far as the Earth Engine API running in your web browser knows, it asked the Earth Engine servers to compute something that *will be a FeatureCollection if the computation succeeds* (because the type of the result of `flatten()` is FeatureCollection). But there was an error instead, and when the Earth Engine Code Editor gets an error from the server, it always displays in this format:

```
<Type of expected result> (Error)
<Error message>
```

This type is intended to help remind you what it was you were trying to compute, since there isn't much other information available.

---

Now I will discuss the specific error “Cannot flatten an object that is not a collection.”

(As of February 28, 2020, this error message has been revised; the new error message is “The input collection must be a collection of collections, but the element with id … was …, which is not a collection.”)

The error is not about the collection, but its contents. The purpose of `flatten` is to convert a collection *containing collections* into a collection of the features in those collections. In your case, as demonstrated by the `print (city_IC)` immediately above, you have an `ImageCollection`, whose contents are always *images*. Images are not collections — they do not contain features. So, you cannot apply `flatten` to an ImageCollection (except in the edge case where the collection is empty).

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but `flatten` is not the right tool to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kevin. appreciate it. 

What I was trying to do, was to export the `imageCollection` as a matrix/dataframe so I can do further analysis on it.
 But I got the result asked in this question

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350517/exporting-imagecollection-using-google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Comment: ... comment [2]

I would like to be able to do [as an example]
{var series2 = ui.Chart.image.doySeriesByYear(
    collection, 'NDVI', forest, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500);}

in my computer. So, I need to export all information of image collection like bands time series as a CSV file lets say

Comment: @NoLie Ah, I understand now. I don't have a good answer for your other question, so it's good that you posted it separately so other people will see it.